# How to uppercase heavily customised sections (sectsty+fontspec)?

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, capitalization, sectsty

I am trying to customise the aspect of a `scrbook` to look like a book I have.

In my case, sections should be formatted as follows: the font face should be `Conques Demi`, the font size `26 pt`, the font colour a particular shade of dark red (CMYK: 0% 87% 87% 50%) with a `1 pt` thick line rule of the same colour that is large the width of a column, the label should be in upper case and aligned to right.

Since I have not managed to realise how to draw coloured line rules with KOMA scripts, I tried to abstain that results with other packages. If you know how to get the exact result that I described above, please feel free to show me how in KOMA! Thanks in advance!

Anyway I managed to mimic the font face, size and colour, the rule and the alignment, but I started to experience problems when I tried to make the label uppercase. Note that the problem persists even if I remove any reference to the `fontspec` package and all its commands. Consider the following *minimal working example*:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\definecolor{darkred}{cmyk}{0.0,0.87,0.87,0.50}
\newfontfamily\myfont[]{Conques}
\sectionfont{\raggedleft\myfont\Huge\color{darkred}\sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-2pt}{1pt}} %

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\section{A Section} % (fold)
\label{sec:a_section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
% section a_section (end)
\end{document}
```

As other answers (to simpler cases) suggest, in order to uppercase the section's label, I am expected to add `\uppercase` to the end of the `\sectionfont{...}` command. If I do so, however, I am warned that a `{` is missing and that `\begin{document}` is closed by `\end{DOCUMENT}`. If I open the resulting `.pdf`, all the document is uppercase except for an additional `A Section` the appear just below the first occurrence and the rule is gone.

This is due to the fact, I think, that `\uppercase` is a *parametric* command while here it is used as an *"absolute"* statement. In my opinion, in fact, the second occurrence of `A Section` is due to `\uppercase` messing with the definition of the section's headings for the table of content, which in turn becomes empty.

According to my researches, there is no such *"absolute"* `\uppercase` equivalent.
Some answers suggest to use `\MakeUppercase` instead as in some cases it is more *"respectful"* of the surrounding environment. If I do so, however, I get the following result: the string `[0pt][r]` at the beginning of an empty line with a rule that is finishing out of the vertical column border; the proper section's label appears below, not uppercased, with no rule, but correctly moved to the right. Even if this might suggest to reorder the commands within `\sectionfont{...}`, no permutation actually works. 
I have even tried with the `textcase` package and its `\MakeTextUppercase` command as well, with no luck at all.

Can someone please tell me where I am wrong and how to fix the issue?

---

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: As far as I know, `sectsty` doesn't allow to put at the end a command with argument; it's `titlesec` that has this feature. However, also the KoMa-Script classes should have some facility for this job, without the need of external packages.

Comment: It's a pity we're not allowed to use KOMA's own setup commands. It'd be rather easy, then.

Comment: My main concern in regards of KOMA commands is that I have found no evidence that they allow to define line rules like `\sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-2pt}{1pt}`. Do you know if they indeed do allow that? I'm editing my question to include this possibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If KOMA's `\setkomafont{section}{<decl>}` can be used then the task is rather easy since the last command in there may have an argument. KOMA doesn't have a `\sectionrule` but one can define something similar using LaTeX's `\rule[<raise>]{<width>}{<thickness>}` command.

So maybe something like the following:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrbook}

% choose the font:
\usepackage{fontspec}
% I don't have `Conques' installed, so I use another font
% I also added a `LetterSpace' greater than zero as all-caps
% words _always_ should be spaced out a little
\newfontfamily\sectionfont[LetterSpace=2]{Linux Libertine O}

% define the color:
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkred}{cmyk}{0.0,0.87,0.87,0.50}
\colorlet{section}{darkred}

% the section layout:    
\newcommand\sectionrule{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[-.25ex]{\linewidth}{1pt}}}
\newcommand\sectionformat[1]{%
  \sectionfont\Huge\color{section}%
  \sectionrule
  \hfill\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\setkomafont{section}{\sectionformat}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\section{A Section}\label{sec:a_section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule...}` would be better than skipping back by `\linewidth`. However this would not work for multiline section titles.

Comment: You might instead define a new command such as `\newcommand\printsectiontitle[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}\makebox[0pt][r]{\rule...}}` and use `\printsectiontitle` as the last command in `\setkomafont{section}`

Comment: @egreg Yes, that would be better and if it was my document I'd probably define some `\sectionformat{<arg>}` command and used it as only argument to `\setkomafont`. I consider that fine-tuning which I haven't done in my answer. Maybe I should, though...

Comment: Dear **cgnieder** and **egreg**, thanks for both the solution and insightful suggestions to my problem! Now it works... and also reasonably well! I'm doing more experiments but I consider the problem solved. The above short discussion about best practices is very interesting as well, thanks for sharing! Regards.

Comment: @StefanoBragaglia You're welcome :)