# Help for reproducing this page with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am not new to LaTex/XeLaTeX, but, I am new to the TikZ world, I want to put the number page and the name of the book (or what ever) as this example: http://www.insecurityinsight.org/files/humanitarianexchange047.pdf, the number of the book is inside a red square, and the title of the book is in the side and both of them are in the edge of the open pages (remember is a book). Could you help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Could you edit your question to show what you've tried already, and where you get stuck? Questions that essentially say "Do this for me, please" are not really a good fit for this site.

Comment: You can start looking at [Headers and page numbers in external borders](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94703/1952)

Comment: @Jake, thank you for  welcome me to the site. I perfectly understand your point and I am shamed for this kind of question, but I don't know anything about TikZ (well, I used it for some drawing of electric circuits, but that's all), so I don't know how to start. But,  I am not looking for "Do this for me, please", instead I'm looking for a answer of the type of Ignasi. I will take your advice in the following questions.

Comment: @Ignasi, thank you for your link. That would be an excellent place to start.

Comment: TikZ provides a very helpful `current page` node. [In this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73620/7279) I gave a very basic example. Other answers deal with solutions with PSTricks. so have a look!

Comment: @Ignasi Implementing headers and page numbers n external borders alone isn't enough. The main reason why the document looks so good is because the height of the captions and the distance between the captions and the paragraphs are very carefully chosen so as not to break the rhythm of the leading (interline spacing).

Comment: I would make the color background separately (using Tikz) and use it for wallpaper for the text (using regular LaTeX).