# Advanced graphical formatting for LaTeX: graphics outside margins

Tags: graphics

I've been learning LaTeX for a year now, and I've gotten quite confident with it when it comes to academics texts. I am really happy with how my thesis worked out.

Now, I want to start making more visually appealing and less appealing documents.

What I want to do and have currently no idea how, is to put horizontal color boxes in the absolute margin of the left side, so as there is no white in the left side of the page.

More or less what I want to do can be seen in this document (made by word):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0LE3gpWwmAaYmo5QzhZRmRZMUk/edit?usp=sharing

Any idea on how to tackle this?

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94430/headers-and-page-numbers-in-external-borders) is similar to yours. I think the solution will involve the `tikz` package but I'm not so experienced yet for suggest you something more useful.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

The way to put something at a fixed location is to put it in the page head:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\makeatletter
\def\@oddhead{%
\setlength\unitlength{1cm}%
\linethickness{.5cm}%
\kern-1in
\kern-\oddsidemargin\begin{picture}(0,0)
{\color{red}\put(0,4){\line(0,-1){4}}}%
{\color{blue}\put(0,-0){\line(0,-1){4}}}%
{\color{yellow}\put(0,-4){\line(0,-1){4}}}%
{\color{green}\put(0,-8){\line(0,-1){4}}}%

\end{picture}\hfill}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

hello

\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, awesome. my document will look great thanks to you