# Section title opposite to the logo

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning, fancyhdr, tikz-styles

Could you please advise me how I could change that code from [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94430/headers-and-page-numbers-in-external-borders) 
to place the section title opposite to the logo?
I am new in LaTeX and I would be very grateful for advice.

For example:

- 1st page: `logo...............section`
- 2nd page: `section............logo`

Comment: Welcome! Can you please post a small, minimal example document we can work with? Unless you really want almost identical output to that in the linked question, there are almost certainly simpler ways to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it in that way:

```
'% section layout:
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\newcommand\sectionrule{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[-.25ex]{\linewidth}{1pt}}}
\newcommand\sectionformat[1]{
  \sffamily\huge\color{darkred}
  \sectionrule
  \ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}
  {\MakeUppercase{#1}}
  {\hfill\MakeUppercase{#1}}
  }
\setkomafont{section}{\sectionformat}'
```